# Can't overwrite multiple classes based on body class

Tags: css

I am playing with prism.css, there is a css declaration like this:

```css
.token.function, .token.namespace, .token.pseudo-element, .token.class, .token.class-name, .token.pseudo-class, .token.id, .token.url-reference .token.variable, .token.attr-name {
     color: red;
}
```

and if I want to overwrite this based on a **body class (dark)**:

```css
body.dark .token.function, .token.namespace, .token.pseudo-element, .token.class, .token.class-name, .token.pseudo-class, .token.id, .token.url-reference .token.variable, .token.attr-name {
      color: blue;
    }
```

it will always apply `color: blue`, even the body doesn't have the ".dark" class. However if I left only one css class like this:

```css
.token.function {
  color: red;
}

body.dark .token.function {
  color: blue;
}
```

then this will work based on the body class.

Comment: You only have the `body.dark` on the first selector, so the rest go by order in the CSS file

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If I have one class or then classes after `body.dark`, what is the difference. If there is only one class then everything works, if there are more than one classes then it does not.

Comment: Each entry is it's own selector, there is no shared parts in list like this, so you need to have the full selector path for each entry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) `CSS` [`pseudo-class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

```css
body.dark :is(.token.function, .token.namespace, .token.pseudo-element, .token.class, .token.class-name, .token.pseudo-class, .token.id, .token.url-reference .token.variable, .token.attr-name) {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Nice, could be optimized a little : `body.dark  .token:is( .function, .namespace,  ..etc ..)`

Answer (score 0):

You are only modifying `body.dark .token.function` , ie `.token.function` you need to add the `body.dark` selector to all the other selectors after the initial comma:

```
 body.dark .token.function, body.dark .token.namespace, body.dark .token.pseudo-element, body.dark .token.class, body.dark .token.class-name, 
 body.dark .token.pseudo-class, body.dark .token.id, body.dark .token.url-reference,  body.dark .token.variable, body.dark .token.attr-name {
      color: blue;
    }
```

Whitout knowing much about your markup or CSS you could try.

```
 body.dark .token {
      color: blue;
 }
```

Comment: Is there a better way without using SCSS?